# Intel MKL Error with Gaussian Fitting in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, intel-mkl

I'm doing a Monte Carlo simulation in Python in which I obtain a set of intensities at certain 2D coordinates and then fit a 2D Gaussian to them. I'm using the scipy.optimize.leastsq function and it all seems to work well except for the following error:
**Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 6 was incorrect on entry to DGELSD.** 
The problem occurs multiple times in a simulation. I have looked around and understand it is something to do with a bug in Intel's MKL library. I can't seem to find a solution to the problem and so I was looking at an alternative fitting function In could use. If someone does know how to get rid of the problem that would be good also.

Comment: I've had errors like this when linking with library for wrong integer size (c interface); e.g.  mkl_intel_lp64.lib vs  mkl_intel_ilp64.lib  . https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html#gs.xbacf0

Answer (score -1):

You could try Intel's python distribution. It includes a pre-built scipy optimized with MKL.